# custom function with std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I see everyone using : 
    `return a.size() < b.size()`

in a custom boolean function used in the sort algorithm, this sorts the values ascending, would

```
return a.size() > b.size()
```

be sufficient to sort descending?

Comment: Ehm, yes. Why haven't you tried it?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Uh, if you're asking, that means I shouldn't be. Maybe I'm just being dull, but why? I assume that's sorting a collection of containers based on the size of those containers?

Comment: @AndyProwl it might work, but I'm not sure. If strict ordering is required on `<`, the strict `>` might not work. I'm probably wrong though :)

Comment: Let the farming begin. Who can write "Yes" plus min character limit in the most interesting way?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I think it would matter, if `std::sort` was stable, but it isn't.

Comment: Well, do accept the top answer at least...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes <sup>in many cases</sup>

Many sort functions use **lessThan** functions to sort ascending. So, `>` is useful to sort descending.

For example, [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in **ascending** order.
>
> comp - comparison function which returns ​true if the first argument is **less
>   than** the second.

Note that, maybe a sort function excepts greaterThan input, or they sort in descending by default. In this case you should use `<`.